# Design pattern to evaluate different type set of rules

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I have a set of different type of rules to be evaluated. Each rule has different statistics,

- each rule is in different database tables.
- evaluating logic is different for each rule type
- different messages have to be generated based on the evaluation.
- status of evaluation should be saved to each rule's database table.

I'm planning to implement it based on Builder pattern, with the following code snippet

```
foreach(Rule rule in Rules){
  var result = rule.evaluate();
  var message = rule.getMessage(result);
  rule.saveMassage(message);
  rule.updateDB(result);
}
```

Here the Rule is the base type and there are sub-types for each rule type which holds properties of the rule.

Is my approach OK? or a better way of doing it?

Comment: How do you relate this code to Builder design pattern?

Comment: @Polymorphic I agree my implementation is not exactly follow Builder pattern. Here I have to execute the same set of methods on a different set of objects in the same family. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any active forum or something to discuss about design patterns? I would be helpful to get experts opinion for beginners to learn these things.

Answer (score 2):

I think your solution is OK. But if you you want to improve design, you have two options:

1) Move this call sequence into a method inside Rule base class.

2)if you are not allowed to modify rule class interface, you need to implement Facade pattern in order to simplify Rule class usages.

Comment: I think your opinion makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @Polymorphic, Here with my implementation, Data and the behavior both are in the same model. Should I separate them? How can I seperate them?

Answer (score 1):

First need to clarify what the Builder pattern is. By its definition in the book Head First Design Patterns:

```
Use the Builder Pattern to encapsulate the construction of a product and 
allow it to be constructed in steps.
```

From your problem description I don't know which objects are 'materials' to build up a Rule. I would suggest you using the Decorator pattern instead.

```
public interface Rule {
    public void evaluate();
}

public class RuleType1 implements Rule {
    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        //Evaluation Logic of Type 1
    }
}

public class RuleType2 implements Rule {
    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        //Evaluation Logic of Type 2 
    }
}

public class RuleEvaluator implements Rule {
    private Rule rule;

    public RuleEvaluator(Rule rule) {
        this.rule = rule;
    }

    @Override
    public void evaluate() {
        // 1. Evaluation logic
        this.rule.evaluate();
        // 2. Update message
        // 3. Update status
        // 4. Update database
    }
}

public class RuleDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Get the list of rules
        for(Rule rule : rules) {
            Rule temp = new RuleEvaluator(rule);
            temp.evaluate();
        }
    }
}
```